# Origine et registre du sens «étudiant paresseux» pour «cancre»

Tags: usage, étymologie, histoire

On lit ici http://etudiant.aujourdhui.fr/etudiant/info/la-france-cancre-de-l-europe-en-anglais.html :

> Pour ce qui est de la maîtrise de la langue anglaise,  la France se classe parmi les cancres de l'Europe.

Selon mon dictionnaire « cancre » signifie « étudiant paresseux ».
D'où provient cette signification ? Ce mot appartient-il au registre soutenu ?

Comment: [*Il dit non avec la tête mais il dit oui avec le cœur il dit oui à ce qu'il aime il dit non au professeur*](http://www.unjourunpoeme.fr/poeme/le-cancre)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Cancre* désigne un élève ayant de mauvais résultats scolaires (pas spécialement du niveau universitaire ou supérieur, on peut parler de *cancre* pour un élève de primaire, de collège ou de lycée).

D'après le dictionnaire du CNRTL, *cancre* serait apparenté au mot *cancer* désignant un crabe, par métaphore avec la démarche oblique, et donc lente, du crabe.

Il s'agit d'un mot courant, il n'appartient pas spécialement au registre soutenu.

On peut l'utiliser comme métaphore pour quelqu'un ou quelque chose qui se place tout au bas d'un classement, à cause de manque d'efforts ou de résultats. C'est le cas dans votre exemple tiré du *Monde*. A contrario, on peut utiliser la même logique métaphorique et dire par exemple *La France est la bonne élève au sein de l'UE et se classe première en matière d'alphabétisation*.

Answer (score 0):

Ah pardon!  Un cancre n'est pas seulement paresseux, il est surtout bête !  Un élève mediocre peut glisser dans la cancritude par paresse, mais un vrai cancre est indécrottable :-)

Comment: Erreur, il n’est pas bête, mais refuse de s’adapter à un monde qui n’est pas fait pour lui… et il déploie une intelligence de l’esquive hors du commun selon l’adage :  « Si je te donne mon petit doigt, tu vas me prendre tout le bras » … c’est même le paradigme du refus de s’engager et de si confronter à l’obstacle. Être Français et cancre en anglais, c’est normal depuis Jeanne d’Arc, mais pour le reste il y a bon nombre de domaines où les Français excellent :-)