# "To go from zero to hero"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

I was talking to my colleagues about one Mechanics book and I wanted to say something like

> With this book any student may go from zero to hero.

Or equivalently

> This book may take any student from zero to hero.

See https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+from+zero+to+hero for the appropriate definition

> To change an outcome, one's situation, or oneself from being particularly unsuccessful, negative, unfortunate, or unpopular to being especially successful, positive, fortunate, or popular.

Here I wanted to imply that any student may pass from a negative to a very positive outcome after reading this book.

I was not sure if

> Ce livre peut faire passer n'importe quel élève de zéro à héros.

or

> Avec ce livre, n'importe quel élève peut passer de zéro à héros.

sound sufficiently idiomatic so I said it in a periphrastic way. So can *de zéro à héros* be used in this way? What are some other colloquial ways to express a similar idea in French?

Comment: Yes you can say *de zéro à héros*, you can also say *de novice / de débutant à expert*.

Comment: @stbr Thanks a lot. Feel free to add it as a reply. One may also say de null à expert I guess:-)! Null est à la mode. Python pour les nulls. Physique pour les nulls, etc.

Comment: If I'am right *nulls* here is just the name of the book series, *nul à expert* would be understood but it would not be a common idiom =)

Comment: @LPH Begone Satan. Pack off! Rest away! Vade retro! Out of here! Away with you!

Comment: Your mention of *nul* tempts me to wonder how/if "...peut passer de nul à chier à expert chiant" would be understood!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure *passer de zéro à héros* has become a set expression like in English.  But it would be understood without any problem.  In the context of learning and school, you could say :

- Ce livre peut faire d'un cancre un premier de la classe.

Or, to quote the Gospel, :

- Avec ce livre, les derniers seront les premiers.

Comment: Oui cancre ! Je te remercie. Je l'avais oublié : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32844/origine-et-registre-du-sens-%c3%a9tudiant-paresseux-pour-cancre/32852#32852

Comment: Certes l'expression n'existe pas en français, mais vu que l'allitération passe dans la traduction, c'est dommage de remplacer ça par quelque chose de plus quelconque.

Comment: @MathieuBouville Je ne dis pas qu'elle est à bannir, simplement qu'elle est moins courante qu'en anglais.  Elle s'impose peut-être plus difficilement à cause de la succession de trois sons vocaliques /zeʀoaeʀo/ qu'elle produit et à laquelle le français rechigne un peu, il me semble.

Comment: "Les derniers seront les premiers" n'a pas du tout la même signification. A la limite "Les derniers deviendront les premiers", mais ca n'est pas la plus vendeuse des formules non plus.

Comment: @LaurentS. C'est également ce que je me suis dit, mais voyant le nombre d'upvote je me suis dit que je devais me tromper.

Comment: @stbr > j'ai moi-même upvoté car en dehors de cette remarque le reste de la réponse est correct.

Comment: A mon avis la réponse devrait-être modifiée avant d'être validée et de recevoir plusieurs upvotes sinon ça ne fait que la valider (intégralement alors qu'au final seulement un exemple sur deux est correct). La preuve, j'ai moi-même commencé à douter alors que je connais pourtant le sens de cette expression.

Comment: @LaurentS derniers = zéro, premiers = héros, où est le problème?

Comment: @petitrien Le sens est différent, une définition de *les derniers seront les premiers* que je viens de trouver sur internet et qui me semble tout à fait pertinente est *Les vainqueurs ne sont pas toujours ceux que l’on croit*. Dans *passer de zéros à héros* il y a une notion de certitude, tandis que *les derniers seront les premiers* inclut juste une possibilité.

Answer (score 4):

As it's about scaling the improvement of a performance, I'd say that "*some other colloquial ways to express a similar idea in French*" could be achieved with:

**Ce livre fera passer vos étudiants de l'abîme à la cime**. (raising from bottom to top).

It conveys the same idea, keeping a similar sound for both words: "*hero / zero*" and "*abîme / cime*".

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can say

> de zéro à héros

You can also say

> de novice / de débutant à expert

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but as a native, I really disagree with everything I found here. I think that the best is just to admit that we don't have this kind of expression in French. For this kind of things, we usually use a reference to a famous brand of books treating every kind of subjects and aiming exactly at making people go from zero to hero.

Personally, I would say:

> Ce livre, c'est vraiment la mécanique pour les nuls

Or perhaps:

> Ce livre, ça devrait être le livre de chevet des étudiants en mécanique

Another approach would be:

> Avec ce livre, n'importe qui peut maîtriser la mécanique
>
> Avec ce livre, n'importe quel étudiant peut devenir un génie de la mécanique
>
> Avec ce livre, même un novice peut devenir expert en mécanique

Answer (score 2):

Autre proposition :
Avec ce livre, vos étudiants passeront d'une bande de zéros à une troupe de héros !

Answer (score 0):

Complément :

Il existe aussi la variante *de zéro en héros* comme on voit dans le titre et les paroles de l'interpretation française de la bande sonore du film Hercules

> De zéro en héros
>
> C'est géant, Herc est dans le vent D'allégresse en Grèce, on chante
>   qu'il est le plus grand C'est un pro, l'Appollo du show Un monstre
>   sacré qui met tous les monstres K.O.   Il n'était personne, un zéro,
>   zéro Il tire le banco, c'est un héros   Lui, le marmot qui ne disait
>   mot De zéro en héros, il a changé de peau Zéro en héros, Illico
>
> He's huge, Herc is all the rage. For fun in Greece, they sing that he is the greatest. He's a pro, the Appollo of the show A hero who knocks
>   out all the monsters.   He was nobody, a zero, a zero He hits the
>   jackpot, he's a hero   Him, the kid who didn't say a word From zero to
>   hero, he changed his skin. Zero to hero, real quick

https://lyricstranslate.com

Voici un exemple d'emploi de *zero à héros*:

https://www.fowcs.com/2019/01/14/fridayshag-2/

Comment: This is not idiomatic. This is just for the rhyme, and it would sound weird in any other context

Answer (score -4):

Au lire des réponses qui précèdent, cette expression vient tout droit de l'anglais et elle n'a rien à envier à aucune autre venant de ces régions-là sur le plan du cachet habituel que l'on peut leur reconnaître ; la proximité des sons est certes un aspect intéressant, mais on voit que l'on paie pour cette fioriture le prix de passer un peu du coq à l'âne. Je ne conçois pas l'idée de la possible glorification populaire du travailleur intellectuel comme une réalité, ni même comme souhaitable. On n'a jamais parlé de personnages comme Pythagore, Newton, Einstein et de nombreux autres en tant que héros ; leur destiné a été la gloire, mais celle des grands hommes, pas celle des héros et on n'appelle pas ces derniers de grand hommes très facilement. Je pense qu'introduire une telle expression dans le français pervertit la culture, déplace ses notions de façon fantaisiste et vaine et je la rejette en bloc : je ne pense pas que reconnaitre la volonté de se lancer dans une activité avec l'idée préconçu d'y devenir un des gourous comme  louable aille dans le sens du progrès intellectuel.

Je m'en tiendrais à une expression plus sobre à tous les points de vue, même si apparemment elle ne fait pas autant impression ;

> Ce livre peut amener n'importe quel élève de A à Z sans effort.

ou

> Avec ce livre, n'importe quel élève peut passer sans effort de A à Z.

COMPLÉMENT (10/08/2019)

Après avoir lu et étudié la trouvaille ingénieuse de user **[MercrediAndThenJedi](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37916/17649)** je trouve que si le mot « cime » convient très bien, le choix de « abîme » n'est pas si heureux. Il n'y a pas de problème pour justifier « cime » come le montre le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cime) ;

> Au fig. 1. Le degré le plus élevé, le paroxysme, l'apogée.

Il n'en va pas de même pour « abîme » ; c'est un mot qui touche le concept plus précis recherché mais qui est quelque peu ambigu ;

> B. Accept. abstr. De manière gén. dans une lang. soutenue ou légèrement teintée de philos., abîme désigne, en parlant d'un inanimé abstr., le plus haut degré concevable, l'insondable ou le mystère, à la limite l'infini ou le néant. Ce qui subsiste de la représentation de l'abîme phys. sert à traduire des idées abstr. plus ou moins suggérées par les attributs concr. (intervalle, parois abruptes, profondeur sans fond) ou une image globale de l'abîme envisagé comme contenant ou comme contenu
>
> 1. Idée d'une oppos. difficile ou impossible à réduire :
>      Avec en outre suggestion d'une idée d'obstacle
> 2. Idée de mystère insondable, d'inconnaissable
> 3. Notion d'infini, parfois associée à l'idée de néant
>      L'inconnu de la vie psychique individuelle, orientée vers un ailleurs, ou telle que le révèlent le rêve ou l'inconscient que cherche à percer la psychanalyse
>      Un sentiment de vide, de néant intérieur (cf. sup. B 3)
> 4. P. ext. et transpos. de plan
>      a) Idée de danger grave, de grande peur

Tous les contextes identifiés ci-dessus correspondent mal au contexte du manque total de connaissances. Le remplacement de « abîme » par nullissime » rend les choses plus claires il me semble ;

- Avec ce livre, n'importe quel étudiant peut passer de nullissime à la cime.

Peut être mieux encore, dans le sens de conserver le parallélisme syntaxique, serait la possibilité suivante ;

- Avec ce livre, n'importe quel étudiant peut passer de nullissime à sublime/éminentissime.

> ([TLFi **II B**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sublime)) [À propos d'une chose] Ce qu'il y a de plus élevé dans l'ordre moral, esthétique, intellectuel.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97181/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-to-go-from-zero-to-hero).

Comment: On traite un sujet de A à Z. On ne progresse pas de A à Z...

Comment: @Sharcoux Je crois qu'il faut être plus libre dans cet usage ; on trouve par exemple « Le professeur à parcouru son cours de A à Z. » ([wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_A_%C3%A0_Z)) ; on peut donc dire aussi « Le professeur à progressé dans son cours de A à Z. »

Comment: `Progressé` ici a le sens de parcours, de 0 à 100%. Dans l'expression zero to hero, on parle de progression personnelle. D'évolution. D'ailleurs, on pourrait progresser en potassant un sujet de Z à A.

Comment: Simplement un truc sur la forme que j'ai remarqué, à ma connaissance le point-virgule n'a pas vocation, contrairement aux deux points, à annoncer la citation ou l'analyse, bof c'est un détail mais c'est un emploi que je trouve personnellement toujours un peu surprenant...

Comment: @personne C'est très vrai et j'en suis conscient moi-même depuis longtemps : le point virgule connecte mais ne « présente » pas ; cependant le deux point  entraine des compromis sur la syntaxe et la ponctuation qui ne me plaisent pas non plus et je l'évite. PS  Ces questions sont loin de paraitre pédante à mon esprit, vous pouvez économiser un « bof » la prochaine fois.